# How to replace a word in a csv file in specific column with python

Tags: python, csv, replace

Good day,

I tried to change a word in a certain column,using index, in a csv file ,but it is not changed.

My code that I tried to use:

```
import csv

with open('INPUT.CSV', 'r') as file1, open('OUTPUT.csv','w',newline='') as file2:
   reader = csv.reader(file1, delimiter=',')
   writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',')

   for row in reader:
        row[0].replace('word','changed word')# I want to replace in first column=row[0] 'word' with 'changed word'
        writer.writerow(row)
```

The output file is same with the input, no changed.

Can someboby help me in this way?Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working example would be better (output is open as `file2` but writer is given `outfile`)

But in any case your problem is `replace`

- `replace` returns a copy of the string (with replaced text if the criteria matches)

But you are discarding the returned value. You are actually changing nothing in `row[0]`

Solution:

```
replaced = row[0].replace('word','changed word')  # I want to replace in first column=row[0] 'word' with 'changed word'
row[0] = replaced
writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you @mementum for your solution...I tried the code with it but it seems that the change is not done only in the specific row (row[x]), it replace all matches that were found...Could be done something in this way?

Answer (score 0):

`row[0].replace()` does not replace anything in row[0]. From the docstring:

> S.replace(old, new[, count]) -> string
>
> Return a copy of string S with all occurrences of substring
>   old replaced by new.  If the optional argument count is
>   given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

If you want to change the value of `row[0]` you need something like `row[0] = new_value`.